# Xsd.exe schema error: Undefined complexType 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:string' is used as a base for complex type restriction

Tags: .net, xsd, xsd.exe

How to solve this problem?

Warning 2 Undefined complexType 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:string' is used as a base for complex type restriction.

This is happening because of **`<xs:simpleContent><xs:restriction base='xs:string'>`**

```
<xs:element name='TO'>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
          <xs:maxLength value='15'/>
          <xs:attribute name='PROVID'>
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base='xs:int'>
                <xs:enumeration value='1'/>
                <xs:enumeration value='2'/>
                <xs:enumeration value='3'/>
                <xs:enumeration value='5'/>
                <xs:enumeration value='6'/>
                <xs:enumeration value='7'/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
          <xs:attribute name='TYPE'>
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
                <xs:enumeration value='NPM'/>
                <xs:enumeration value='EMS'/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

looking at the [W3schools reference](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_restriction.asp) this looks ok, but not according to VS2010 and Xsd.exe

All I really want to do is have a definition for an element TO that can have the two above attributes and its element text should be restricted to 15 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't restrict a string to 15 characters **and** extend it to be a complex type with attributes at the same time. If you first define a restricted string type and then extend it, you won't have a problem:

```
<xs:simpleType name="RestrictedString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="15"/>
    </xs:restriction>   
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="TO">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="RestrictedString">
                <xs:attribute name="PROVID">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                            <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="5"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="6"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="7"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
                <xs:attribute name="TYPE">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="NPM"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="EMS"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```